# Ctrl+C on Java robot is not working

Tags: java, clipboard, awtrobot

I am trying to write a code using Java robot that will copy text using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, and then I read it from the clipboard. The code I used is this:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(1000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(VK_C);
robot.keyRelease(VK_C);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
String str=(String)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```

But `str` does not contain the value that should have been copied.

Comment: `Ctrl + C` does not do what you think it does if you are talking about command line UI. Instead of copying, it usually sends an interrupt to the running program/thread to stop it completely.

Comment: I've solved it. apparently ctrl+c does work but it takes time for the copied text to appear in the clipboard. I added a sleep of 1 second before reading from the clipboard and the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to use Clipboard with Ctrl+c/x/v to attach to a JTextArea, you should use Clipboard, StringSelection and DataFlavour classes. Please consider the following code snippet:

```
@Override
public void lostOwnership(Clipboard clipboard, Transferable contents) {}


public void setClipboardContents(String str){
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(str);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, this);
}



public String getClipboardContents() {
    String result = "";
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();


    Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
    boolean hasTransferableText = (contents != null) && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);


    if (hasTransferableText) {
        try {
            result = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e){
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch(IOException e){
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }


    return result;
}




@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}




@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
        // your code here
    }

    if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_V) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
        // your code here
    }

    if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_X) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
        // your code here
    }
}




@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
```

Of course you should implement KeyListener and ClipboardOwner interfaces too.

I use a swing layout with KeyListener so users can copy/paste there data with Ctrl+c/x/v shortcuts.

However if you would like to use Robot class, see these links:

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt/how-to-use-robot-class-in-java.html

http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-robot-class-example-mouse-keystroke